# Extract audio from a video file saved in the camera roll

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avasset

I have the following code that reads a video file from the camera roll which works perfectly fine

```
Scene *scene = [_sceneArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = scene.src_url;
NSURL *full_url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:full_url options:nil];
AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
```

However, when i try to extract just the audio of a given video file using the following code, the application force closes (with array out of bound exception)

```
audioTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: So.... what does the debugger or `NSLog` tell you about the contents of that array you're looking into? How about some error checking? Array lengths checks?

Comment: The array is empty and it throws "*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array", the sound clip does contain in the  "audioTrack".

Comment: Maybe the sound is not contained in the file

Comment: @CarouselMin, there is sound in the video file, I can confirm that.